# Entity Framework Core 2 - Code first not creating tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2017, .net-core-2.0

Entity Framework Core 2.0 has been [recently released](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/08/14/announcing-entity-framework-core-2-0/) and i am using it.

I have added the following line in method ConfigurationServices() in file Startup.cs (My connectionstring is fine).

```
services.AddDbContext<AutoPartsContext>(options => 
options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("NetCore")));
```

and in Configure method,

```
using (var serviceScope = 
app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
{
var context = 
serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyConntectionStringName>();
context.Database.Migrate();
context.Database.EnsureCreated();
}
```

This is creating the database but not tables. When i call a simple count on my tables,

```
var a = _context.Users.Count();
```

It throws following exception

> Invalid object name 'Users'.
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)

However, if i create table manually, everything works perfectly. I need all tables to be auto created.

EF Core version: 2.0, Database Provider: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer, Operating system: Windows 10, IDE: Visual Studio 2017 Preview 2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use migrations for this, as database initializers that used to exist in pre-Core EF are no longer available.

Please refer to [Migrations - EF Core with ASP.NET Core MVC tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/migrations).

Comment: Thanks, that helped

Comment: *sigh* Why do they insist on taking away things that made our lives easier.  Thanks for this.